# How do you get the Instagram DM ID/URL?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to get the Instagram DM ID so that I can open up an old DM with a friend.[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrlBj.png)

Whenever I try to message them, all our DM history is gone so I am guessing that if I can get this number, and I add it to the URL, I should be able to see all of our previous conversations? We both unfollowed and probably closed the DM, so that might explain why you cant see it.

Any help?!